# Poetry (pyproject.toml) support both Python 2 and 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ipython, tox, python-poetry

I have a package (usignals) that needs to support both Python 2 and 3. In my `pyproject.toml`, I have this:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=2.7, >=3.6"
```

and

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
ipython = [
    {version = "~5", python = "~2.7"},
    {version = "~7.8", python = ">=3.5"}
]
```

When I run tox via `tox -rve py27`, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Package u'usignals-0.4.0' requires a different Python: 2.7.5 not in '>=3.6'
```

Note that if I specify `python = "*"`, then I get `Because usignals depends on both ipython (~5) and ipython (~7.8), version solving failed.` which is no help either.

Note that if I specify `python = "~2.7 || >=3.6"`, I get the same error as before.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Before anyone asks, here is the `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
isolated_build = true
envlist = py27, py36

# Run `pyenv global 3.7.4 system` if pyenv cannot find python2.
[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands =
    poetry install -v
    poetry run pytest tests/
```

Even more verbose output:

```
Resolving dependencies...
   1: fact: usignals is 0.4.0
   1: derived: usignals
   1: fact: usignals depends on click-help-colors (^0.6.0)
   1: fact: usignals depends on click (^7.0)
   1: fact: usignals depends on pymysql (^0.9.3)
   1: fact: usignals depends on coverage (*)
   1: fact: usignals depends on pytest (*)
   1: fact: usignals depends on sphinx (^1.8)
   1: fact: usignals depends on sphinx (^2)
   1: fact: usignals depends on ipython (~5)
   1: fact: usignals depends on ipython (~7.8)
   1: fact: usignals depends on bumpversion (^0.5.3)
   1: fact: usignals depends on docformatter (^1.3)
   1: fact: usignals depends on flake8 (^3.7)
   1: fact: usignals depends on mock (^3.0)
   1: fact: usignals depends on sure (^1.4)
   1: fact: usignals depends on tox (^3.14)
   1: fact: usignals depends on yapf (^0.28.0)
   1: fact: usignals depends on pytest-colordots (^1.1)
   1: fact: usignals depends on pytest-runner (^5.1)
   1: fact: usignals depends on pytest-xdist (^1.30)
   1: selecting usignals (0.4.0)
   1: derived: pytest-xdist (^1.30)
   1: derived: pytest-runner (^5.1)
   1: derived: pytest-colordots (^1.1)
   1: derived: yapf (^0.28.0)
   1: derived: tox (^3.14)
   1: derived: sure (^1.4)
   1: derived: mock (^3.0)
   1: derived: flake8 (^3.7)
   1: derived: docformatter (^1.3)
   1: derived: bumpversion (^0.5.3)
   1: derived: ipython (~7.8)
   1: conflict: usignals depends on ipython (~5)
   1: ! not ipython (~5) is satisfied by ipython (~7.8)
   1: ! which is caused by "usignals depends on ipython (~7.8)"
   1: ! thus: version solving failed
   1: Version solving took 0.016 seconds.
   1: Tried 1 solutions.

[SolverProblemError]                                                          
Because usignals depends on both ipython (~5) and ipython (~7.8), version solving failed.
```

Answer (score 4):

[There was a bug](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/1480) which [has been fixed](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/pull/1482).

For postereity:

```
python = "^2.7 || ^3.6 ||  ^3.7"
```

and

```
ipython = [
    {version = "^5", python = "~2.7"},
    {version = "^7", python = ">=3.5"}
]
```

should be correct. I will test as soon as there is a new release of poetry.

Comment: This works! thank you.